# impossible to get rid off org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, hibernate

I get the title error on a test java project using hibernate.
Nothing on the similar posts helped me to solve this issue.

The concerned class is :

```
package org.entities;

// default package
// Generated Jul 11, 2015 12:18:25 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Rats generated by hbm2java
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "RATS")
public class Rats implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private   int id;
    private Serializable name;
    private   int age;

    public Rats() {
    }

    public Rats(int id, Serializable name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    public Serializable getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(Serializable name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "Age", nullable = false)
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My name is " + name + ", anad I am " + age + " years old.";
    }


}
```

This file is automatically generated by eclipse (except the toString method).
If I replace "serializable" with "String" in the listed beyond class, it will work. But I am sure that you gurus will find the correct reason so that I don t need to do this hack.

If relevant, the "Name" field correspond to a nchar(50) into the DB.

Thx in advance

Comment: So, why do you not want it to be a `String`? Also, why is the field `transient`? Looks to me that you should get rid of that Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I actually added "transient  "  as a test. I had the exception before and after adding it. I ll remove it from the original post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare variable 'name' as private transient  Serializable name; and in your database table the type of column 'Name' is nchar. This is a type mismatch since Serializable is a interface. Because of this hibernate is throwing an exception.

**Solution** Change column type to Blob

Instead of defining name as Serializable name; define it in other way like MyClass name; also MyClass should implement Serializable interface.

[Refer this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)

and [this one also](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html)